# javascript - why are both divs not rotating?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, object, rotation

I have created Square as an object and given it prototype of size and rotate , when i create new square1 and square2 and call rotate on them , only the last created div rotates that is a square, both need to rotate, "I think it may have something to do with className square , but need help fixing it. Both Squares need to be rotating .

Thank you

```
// global variables //

var angle = 0; //initialize angle

// Square Object //

var Square = function() {
    square = document.createElement('div');
    square.className = 'square';
    document.body.appendChild(square); //div created div name class square
}

// prototype size of Square

Square.prototype.size = function(width,height,margin) {
    square.style.width = width + 'px';
    square.style.height = height + 'px';
    square.style.margin = margin + 'px';
} 


//prototype rotate of Square 

Square.prototype.rotate = function rotA() {
    angle = (angle + 1)%360;
    square.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"
    window.requestAnimationFrame(rotA);
}


// create new square -------------
var square1 = new Square();

square1.size(250,250,250);

var square2 = new Square();

square2.size(500,500,125)
square1.rotate();
square2.rotate();
```

see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gustav1105/c41fLbh0/

Comment: It looks like `square = document.createElement('div');` assigns a new `div` to the same variable. This means, when you create the second square, the reference to the first one is lost.

Comment: Also `square` seems to be global variable so basically there is only one square.

Comment: @Xufox thank you how will I be able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` keyword in the function. And need to `bind` the `rotate` function while calling from `window.requestAnimationFrame`

```js
// Square Object //

var Square = function() {
    this.angle = 0;
 this.square = document.createElement('div');
 this.square.className = 'square';
 document.body.appendChild(this.square); //div created div name class square
}

// prototype size of Square

Square.prototype.size = function(width,height,margin) {
 this.square.style.width = width + 'px';
 this.square.style.height = height + 'px';
 this.square.style.margin = margin + 'px';
} 


//prototype rotate of Square 

Square.prototype.rotate = function() {
 this.angle = (this.angle + 1)%360;
 this.square.style.transform = "rotate(" + this.angle + "deg)"
 window.requestAnimationFrame(this.rotate.bind(this));
}


// create new square -------------
var square1 = new Square();
square1.size(250,250,250);

var square2 = new Square();
square2.size(500,500,125);

square1.rotate();
square2.rotate();
```

```css
.square {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x99hLp50/1/), not quite object-oriented as you would like it to be but you can use it if you didn't find any other solution

```
// global variables //

var angle = 0; //initialize angle

// Square Object //

var Square = function() {
    var square = document.createElement('div');
    square.className = 'square';
    square.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    document.body.appendChild(square); //div created div name class square
    return square;
}

// prototype size of Square

Square.size = function(square, width,height,margin) {
    square.style.width = width + 'px';
    square.style.height = height + 'px';
    square.style.margin = margin + 'px';
} 


//prototype rotate of Square 

Square.rotate = function rotA(square) {
    angle = (angle + 1)%360;
    square.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){ rotA(square) });
}


// create new square -------------
var square1 = new Square();
console.log(square1);
Square.size(square1,25,25,25);

var square2 = new Square();

Square.size(square2,25,25,25)
Square.rotate(square1);
Square.rotate(square2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As  @gurvinder372 suggested, square is not defined locally for each Square object,
the the code just "forgets" the first instance.

Please use the `this` keyword to refer to instance variables inside prototype extensions.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8ppv0py/2/)